# Building a C# WinForms application with a local Db

Tags: c#, winforms, localdb

I am trying to build my first .exe from a c# winforms project. I am using the Flexera Installing Shield. So far I can build and install it and it runs successfully on the same machine where I am developing. In this project I am using a local db. I can also install it on another machine, but as soon as I`m trying to access the Db via a button it complains. I think it has something to do with the connection string. At least it complains at the line where I am trying to access the Db with:

```
Error 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified
```

Here is my obviously wrong connection string:

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=""C:\Users\idiot\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Vis\Vis\LocalDbVisTest.mdf"";Integrated Security=True";
```

Thank you for any help or hint in advance!

Comment: did you copy the database along with your program? It will need to reside in this path: `C:\Users\idiot\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Vis\Vis\LocalDbVisTest.mdf`

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you build and run the created installer manually? If so, if could be a configuration issue with Flexara.

Comment: No, I built the .exe on my machine where I develop, and installed it on another machine, where it does not work.
I have no idea how to build manually. Sorry, first time I try to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using an absolute path for your connection string, use

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\LocalDbVisTest.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

The reason your program cannot find the database is because it is looking in

```
C:\Users\idiot\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Vis\Vis\LocalDbVisTest.mdf
```

Which, presumably, doesn't exist on your client's machine.

You can manually set your `DataDirectory` by using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", path)`. You can get the path of your executable by using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

Comment: Thx, I just built it new. It works so to say better. But it complains that the database is read-only?

Comment: Hmm not sure about that one I'm afraid! Sorry.

Comment: @dav_i You are going to have to change the permissions for the Db.

Comment: @Dozer: any idea where I can change the permissions for the local Db?

Comment: I don't really know very much about web hosting, but the only way I could answer that, would be if knew what hosting provider you were using.